# ReactJS compontent state not update correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Consider I got a component called `Test`

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Test = (props) => {
    const [Amount, setAmount] = useState(1);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.defaultAmount){
            setAmount(props.defaultAmount)
        }
        props.getResult(Amount);
    },[props, Amount])
    return (
        <>
            <span>Amount is: {Amount}</span>
            <input value={Amount} onChange={(e)=>setAmount(e.target.value)}/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

I use this in two different components (actually my pages), one with `defaultAmount` another without.

**Page 1:**

```
<Test getResult={getAmountResult} defaultAmount={25}/>
```

*But this not update result and it back to default one!*

**Page 2:**

```
<Test getResult={getAmountResult} />
```

*it works fine!*

**[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-galois-qhdzes)**

Is there any solution to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your code like this

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Test = (props) => {
    const [Amount, setAmount] = useState(1);


    useEffect(() => {
        props.getResult(Amount);
    }, [Amount])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.defaultAmount){
            setAmount(props.defaultAmount)
        }
    },[props.defaultAmount])
    return (
        <>
            <span>Amount is: {Amount}</span>
            <input value={Amount} onChange={(e)=>setAmount(e.target.value)}/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

in your current implementation you always overwrite the amount state with the default

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` function is the culprit. You're setting the `Amount` back to `defaultAmount` everytime `Amount` changes, thus overriding the user input.

Try updating the condition within `useEffect` before you set the value, to make sure you don't override the user input, something like:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(props.defaultAmount && Amount === 1){ // Checking if the amount is still the initial value
        setAmount(props.defaultAmount)
    }
    props.getResult(Amount);
},[props, Amount])
```

Answer (score 1):

When input changes, setAmount called, it will update amount and trigger useEffect hook which will set amount to default value. Try this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Test = (props) => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(props.defaultAmount);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (amount) {
      props.getResult(amount);
    }
  }, [amount, props]);

  return (
    <>
      <span>Amount is: {amount}</span>
      <input value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```